# Azure Function app : Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'receiverConnectionString')

Tags: python, azure, function

I follow below structures, but after uploading function app on, I face error:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=python

Error:

Function (transformation/EventHubTrigger1) Error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.EventHubTrigger1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'receiverConnectionString').
Session Id: cb179cdab03c4e8c80f1f82d9da9d143

Timestamp: 2020-03-11T15:55:55.575Z

[image]

---

```
Function.json :
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "iothub-ehub-neas-hub-xxx-xxxx",
      "connection": "Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxx=;EntityPath=iothub-ehub-neas-hub-xxxxxx-856659355a",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you need to regenerate your IoT Hub access keys now! I just removed it from your code but they have now been exposed. Please never post your real access keys!

Comment: Thank you so much, the key was not real :)

Answer (score 9):

you need to put the endpoint information in your local.settings.json and reference it from the function.json. The XXXX is just to show the is more. The connection strings are what you get in the event hub portal. i had the same issue setting up in node.

Local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureEventHubConnectionString": "Endpoint=XXXX",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=XXXX"
  }
}
```

Then in your function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "IoTHubMessages",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "<event hub name you have>",
      "connection": "AzureEventHubConnectionString",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

That will get rid of the receiverConnectionString error.

Answer (score 1):

In the `connection` field you do not put in the connection string itself. Instead you put in the name (i.e. Key) of an [application setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings). In this one you put in the connection string.

Comment: But still the error remain. Do you have any idea about it : Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'receiverConnectionString').

Comment: are you sure you have set it properly in the app settings and updated your function.json accordingly?

Comment: btw, not sure if it is case sensitive, but usually it is `function.json`

Comment: I think the function.json is not correct. do you know where I can find the "EventHubName" and "Connection"? I used IoT Hub and Built-in-Endpoint

Comment: So strange but it worked for me. Should work both ways if you ask me

Answer (score 0):

Following up from Martin Naughton's post, also, you need to ensure you have the connection string name in the function's Run method:

```
   public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "AzureEventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
```

Comment: .. and if you don't have the function.json file locally you will have to create it from scratch in your Visual Studio solution.